# we are getting order in magento site if customer don't pay in "payment[payumoney india]" site

Tags: payment

we are using payu in our "MAGENTO" site :

payu is "payment method" in india as like paypal.

It's really strange that payu official code did't work well

after customer buy the product, than he went to "checkout" page ,

he click on "place order" button , after that it will redirect to "payu site"

he did't paid money but he can close the  payu site without paying, but than also we will recieve the "order".

we don't want this to be happen . in magento admin panel, we should get "order" only after customer paid the money in payu.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the way it works is that only those orders should be considered which are in processing state.

The way payment gateways work in magento is that if you create the order and don't make a payment the order remains in pending state and should be cancelled since a payment has not been made. So you should ask your business to ignore orders in pending state.

If that is something business is not ready to accept you could add a filter to the grid collection.

Over-write: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid::_prepareCollection() to add status filter to orders. Something like `$collection->addFieldToFilter('status',array('neq'=>'pending');`

However, this isn't a recommended solution.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply,  can you please send/post the files that you updated in payu extension?

Comment: How we will get information about whether customer paid the money or not in payu?